# How to use LESS version of bootstrap in Visual Studio? How to enable auto-compilation to CSS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Do you use Bootstrap written in *.LESS in your ASP.net project? How do you include it to project?

In Visual Studio with "Web Essentials" plugin, you can create *.less file and every time when you save changes, the new CSS file is automatically created. This generated CSS file is used in web pages.

I [downloaded Bootstrap (Source code)](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and there I've found a dozen of *.less files. **What is the best way to make VisualStudio compile it to one *.css bootstrap file?**